# Transaction does not work with WSO2 dbReport Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. The [DB Report Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/DB+Report+Mediator) attribute transaction `useTransaction` does not seem to be working.

Here is the sample code used.
In this code, the insert to table1 still gets committed even when there is an exception from the insert to table2. Both DMLs are against the same datasource and we really do not need XA support.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="TransactionSample"
          onError="ErrorSequence"
          trace="enable"
          statistics="enable">
   <transaction action="new"/>
       <dbreport useTransaction="true">
          <connection>
         <pool>
            <dsName>ds1</dsName>
         </pool>
          </connection>
          <statement>
         <sql>insert into table1(X) values ('X')</sql>           
          </statement>
          <statement>
         <sql>insert into table2(Y) values ('Y')</sql>           
          </statement>
       </dbreport>
    <transaction action="commit"/>
</sequence>

<sequence name="ErrorSequence">            
    <transaction action="rollback"/>
        <send/>
</sequence>
```

Any pointers to this would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it will work with same database with single data source. Transaction used for distributed databases. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Transaction+Mediator+Example. You may used DSS with boxcarring

Comment: What database are you using ? I know that MySQL with MyISAM tables ignore transactions

Comment: Both statements are supposed to run in the same transaction when "useTransaction" is "true". Is your datasource configured to operate in autocommit mode ?

Comment: Oracle 11G. My datasource is defined using the admin UI and I have used the defaultAutoCommit value as false.